# iPhone - IMA WAV ADPCM audio stream for iOS

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, vlc

I am trying to write an app for a school project that will play a video stream of the lab. They use Foscam cameras, and from what I understand they only stream audio in FFMPEG and VLC (a wrapper of FFMPEG and others, correct?). I can play the video stream in a UIWebView just fine, but I can't figure out how to get audio to work. I have read a bunch of post on here about the different audio stream options, but none support this format. I have also looked into VLCKit, but that seems to only work in OS X, not iOS.

Is there a Framework, or Kit that can stream IMA WAV ADPCM audio from a VLC/FFMPEG file, or does someone know of a better way to get audio from a Foscam?

EDIT - I know more about the stream and I have tried a few things. I tried AVPlayer, but discovered Audio FIle Stream and Audio Queue Services but can't find a good tutorial.

I also found [THIS](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html) site, and tried the project with my stream and it did not work.

Comment: Don't foscam camera's support  rtsp and mjpeg, I believe the audio feed is RTP from the camera, so the stream is ADPCM, you most likely need audioUnits to do that, we have a commercial api for that but I can't think of an open source one because it can be quite painful to make that work.

Comment: Thanks! I have never heard of audioUnits, is there a link for it?

Comment: its an apple api, you might just be better off letting us help you with this. Please contact us. We are always happy to further education